# how to configure an .htaccess rule to allow read only access to all user on a specific graphics file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony-2.8, file-access

In my web-app that is written in php and using Symfony v2.8, I have a contact page that when submitted to the server creates two emails that should include a graphic, but when this graphic is actually included I get the following error:

```
Unable to open file for reading 
[https://fake.net/Resources/public/images/landing_page/mypic.png]
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_IoException

Stack Trace
in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php
at line 144  -
    if (!isset($this->_reader)) {
        $pointer = @fopen($this->_path, 'rb');
        if (!$pointer) {
            throw new Swift_IoException(
                'Unable to open file for reading ['.$this->_path.']'
            );
        }
```

However, the problem isn't with the swiftmailer, because if I do not include the graphic, the emails are successfully created and sent.  Alternatively, when the .htaccess, which I'm using to protect my site, is file renamed, the emails are again successfully created and sent when the graphic image included.

Today, while trying to fix this I found that the same graphic that is displayed in several pages of my web-app, is now unable to load when the .htaccess is in place.  The error that I'm now getting is:

```
GET https://fake.net/Resources/public/images/landing_page/mypic.png
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here are the lines that I added to end of my .htaccess file:

```
# Allow access of the mypic logo for emails

<files mypic.png>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</files>
```

Before the above statement are the following line, which have always been in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  <If "%{HTTP_REFERER} != ''">

    # Hot link prevention for css|gif}htm|html|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|php|png files
    # from any other domain than %{HTTP_HOST}
    # See http://tltech.com/info/referrer-htaccess/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .*\.(css|gif}htm|html|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|php|png)$ - [NC,F]

  </If>

</IfModule>
```

While, none of this limits file access to read-only, the file's permission being set to 664 does this.  ***Is this something that .htaccess can do to force read-only access when the file's permission is 666?***

The  statement appears to grant access to any file with that name, not just to the one specific file I want to have unlimited read-only access, which is located in the web\Resources\public\images\landing_page directory.  However, when I try using a relative or absolute path, the email creation still blows-up with the same error.  ***Please, address this in whatever solution is suggested.***

Obviously, the  statement is causing the web-site's problem accessing the graphics.  ***How do I properly override the .htaccess rule controlling access to this file in my emails?***

I was told to move the file out of the area controlled by the .htaccess file, but my whole site is controlled by the .htaccess, so moving the graphic file to the directory above the site's web directory, would make the graphic file beyond the scope of my web-site, so also not available.

Comment: Can’t you just supply a file system path to embed the image into the e-mail, instead of a URL? Then you would not have this issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, but then I would have the extra traffic caused by the emails referencing the image on my server.  By embedding the image, I don't need to worry about that.  Also, people looking at their email while off-line, still see the image.

Comment: That’s not what I meant. I meant read the file from a local file system path, instead of a URL, not change how the image is embedded into the mail.

Comment: I'm already doing that.  $logoImage = $site '/Resources/public/images/landing_page/image.png'; $cid = $message->embed( \Swift_Image::fromPath( $logoImage ) ); $bodyHTML = '<div style="height: 112px">' . '<img src="' . $cid . '" style="width:150px" /></div>' . $messageBody;

Comment: Well then anything in .htaccess can’t be a problem any more. If it is still not working, then most likely you still got the path wrong. Are you sure `Resources` is located at the root of your server file system?